# Herfindahl index using values in last 5 years

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data:

```
gvkey   sic     firm                cusip       year    X       Y       Z       Class

61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2001    5.3     4.8     9.7     356
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2002    5.3     4.8     9.7     358
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2003    5.3     4.8     9.7     358
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2004    5.66    6.22    11.1    548
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2005    5.54    6.90    11.18   72
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2005    5.54    6.90    11.18   156
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2006    5.545   6.90    11.18   206
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2007    5.5     9.3     12.7    53    
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2007    5.5     9.3     12.7    53      
61399   2835    MYRIAD GENETICS INC 62855J104   2007    5.5     9.3     12.7    53
```

My intention is to find herfindahl index for class variable in last 5 years. For example, one will need to pool all "class"es in last 5 years, namely 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003 to calculate the index for 2018 as:

```
 ((1/8)^2 + (1/8)^2 + (1/8)^2 + (1/8)^2 + (1/8)^2 + (3/8)^2) -  The higher index, the lesser a firm has diversified in patent classes. 
  53 is repeated 3 times, the rest only once
```

I can calculate this index for each firm - each year which tells me how diversified a firm is in a given year. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def hhi(series):
    _, cnt = np.unique(series, return_counts=True)
    return np.square(cnt/cnt.sum()).sum()    

new_df = df.groupby(['gvkey', 'year']).agg({'class': hhi})
print(new_df)
```

However, now I need to pool "class" values in last 5 years and then calculate the index. Probably, one will need to add a "condition" to this code which focuses on previous years.

**Note 1:** One can ask that if the index pools last 5 years then in the results first 5 years will be missing. But I intend the code to calculate even if there is **one** previous year. In other words, the cell in the new column will pool all possible years and calculate, but when there are more than 5 previous years the cell will consider only 5 of them (for example 7th year of a firm).

**Note 2:** there are many firms and years, so code should do the same for all groups in the panel.

Intended outcome:

```
gvkey   sic         year    X       Y       Z       Class   HHI
61399   2835        2001    5.3     4.8     9.7     356     a  null
61399   2835        2002    5.3     4.8     9.7     358     b (class values in: 01)
61399   2835        2003    5.3     4.8     9.7     358     c (class values in: 02,01)
61399   2835        2004    5.66    6.22    11.1    548     d (class values in: 03,02,01)
61399   2835        2005    5.54    6.90    11.18   72      e (class values in: 04,03,02,01)
61399   2835        2005    5.54    6.90    11.18   156     e (class values in: 04,03,02,01)
61399   2835        2006    5.545   6.90    11.18   206     f (class values in: 05,04,03,02,01)
61399   2835        2007    5.5     9.3     12.7    53      g (class values in: 06,05,04,03,02)
61399   2835        2007    5.5     9.3     12.7    53      g (class values in: 06,05,04,03,02)
61399   2835        2007    5.5     9.3     12.7    53      g (class values in: 06,05,04,03,02)
61399   2835        2008    5.5     9.3     12.7    53      h (class values in: 07,06,05,04,03)
```

**Note 3:** years can be repeated. Therefore, previous row does not refer to previous year.

**Note 4:** there are missing values in "class" variable. If the value is missing, the code should ignore that cell. The code will need to create a kind of portfolio using last 5 year data. It shouldn't care about missing values

Sorry that it was a bit long, but I wanted to make everything clear. If there is still something you do not get, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Chris have you got  any idea to program this index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself:

First I defined HHI:

```
import numpy as np

def hhi(series):
    _, cnt = np.unique(series, return_counts=True)
    return np.square(cnt/cnt.sum()).sum()
```

Then i duplicated and indexed gvkey and year:

```
merge['year_x'] = merge['year']
merge['gvkey_x'] = merge['gvkey']
merge = merge.set_index(['gvkey_x', 'year_x'])
```

p.s. merge is my data.

As the next I defined a function for a window (4-year):

```
def rollBy(what, basis, window, func):
    def applyToWindow(val):
        chunk = what[(val - window <= basis)  & ( basis < val )] 
        return func(chunk)
    return basis.apply(applyToWindow)
```

In the end I ran rollBy function for each group (gvkey) and appended the dataframes:

```
final_data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in merge['gvkey_x']:
    result = pd.DataFrame(rollBy(merge['class'], merge['year'], 4,hhi))
    final_data = final_data.append(result)
```

It is ready. The final dataframe consists of each firm's 4-year rolling portfolio diversity (diversity of patent classes).